# Can't send hyperlink on email with Python

Tags: python, email, tkinter, hyperlink, smtp

I paste the link in the content message of my email but the link doesn't appear in the email sent.

```
try:
        content = "https://www.google.com/"
        mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        mail.ehlo()
        mail.starttls()
        mail.login('my_emailgmail.com','password')
        mail.sendmail('my_email.gmail.com', "receiver.gmail.com", content)
        mail.quit()
        print("Successfully sent email")
    except:
        print("Nah")
```

Comment: as I know `sendmail` as default send `plain text` and it needs to add special attachment with HTML version.

Comment: do you get empty mail or link as normal text? It may get it as plain text and it may treat it as plain text. Did you try to send as HTML `<a href=https://www.google.com/">https://www.google.com/</a>`

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem using an other method. Here is the code modified:

```
def send_email(recipient, reservation_data):
    sender_email = "sender.gmail.com"
    receiver_email = "reciever.gmail.com"
    password = "password"

    message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
    message["Subject"] = "multipart test"
    message["From"] = sender_email
    message["To"] = receiver_email

    text = """\
    Confirm paying here www.Museums.com"""
    html = """\
    <html>
      <body>
        <p>Hi,<br>
           How are you?<br>
           <a href="www.google.com">Real Python</a> 
           has many great tutorials.
        </p>
      </body>
    </html>
    """
    
    part1 = MIMEText(text, "plain")
    part2 = MIMEText(html, "html")

    message.attach(part1)
    message.attach(part2)

    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465, context=context) as server:
        server.login(sender_email, password)
        server.sendmail(
            sender_email, receiver_email, message.as_string()
        )
```